# How to get aws lambda to exec or run a .ts file when deployed

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, serverless

I have a simple lambda function written in typescript. It works locally using `sls invoke local -f main` however when deployed and i run it in aws console via a test function i get the following error:

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'handler'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'handler'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:951:17)",
    "    at async Object.UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:976:21)",
    "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1137:23)",
    "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1143:1"
  ]
}
```

**serverless.ts**

```
import type { AWS } from "@serverless/typescript";

const serverlessConfiguration: AWS = {
    service: "email-service",
    frameworkVersion: "3",
    plugins: [],
    useDotenv: true,
    provider: {
        name: "aws",
        region: "us-east-2",
        runtime: "nodejs16.x",
        apiGateway: {
            minimumCompressionSize: 1024,
            shouldStartNameWithService: true,
        },
        environment: {
            AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: "1",
            NODE_OPTIONS: "--enable-source-maps --stack-trace-limit=1000",
            FROM_EMAIL: process.env.FROM_EMAIL,
            SENDGRID_API_KEY: process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY,
        },
    },
    // import the function via paths
    functions: {
        main: {
            handler: "handler.main",
            timeout: 60,
        },
    },
    package: { individually: true },
};

module.exports = serverlessConfiguration;
```

The file `handler.ts` exists and there is an exported function called `main`.

**hanlder.ts**

```
import SendEmail from "./src/sendemail";
import { ValidateInput } from "./src/validator";

export const main = async (event, _context) => {
    try {
        const errors = await ValidateInput(event);
        if (errors.length > 0) {
            return { statusCode: 400, body: { errors: errors } };
        }

        const result = await SendEmail(event);
        return { statusCode: 200, body: { data: result } };
    } catch (err) {
        return { statusCode: 500, body: { errors: [err.stack] } };
    }
};
```

Is it possible for aws lambda to run .ts files OR must they be converted to js using something like serverless-esbuild?

Comment: Run tsc and upload the resulting .js files instead

Comment: You need to directly export a function named `handler` that matches the expected arguments  that  AWS lambda will pass in when executing. You can't do anything fancy, in my experience. Plus what the others said-- you need to upload the transpiled javascript, not typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js doesn't run TypeScript code natively
[doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-typescript.html). You have to transpile it to JS code.